# LibreOffice Draw tries to download 27.9 MB data when I try to remove it

Tags: software-center, uninstall, libreoffice, software-uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall libreoffice on Ubuntu Software Center. But it says it will also remove Impress as well. When I confirm, it starts downloading some 27.9 MB data. Why is this so?

Update:

Trying to do this using `apt-get`, I get the following:

```
me@my-computer:~$ sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-draw 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-writer python3-uno
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-base libopencl1 libreoffice-style-crystal
  libreoffice-style-hicontrast libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-evolution libreoffice-gcj
  libreoffice-java-common default-jre gcj-jre openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre
  sun-java5-jre sun-java6-jre java5-runtime jre
Recommended packages:
  libreoffice-math
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreoffice-draw libreoffice-impress libreoffice-ogltrans
  libreoffice-presentation-minimizer
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-writer python3-uno
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.9 MB/64.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.6 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: Use the `apt-get` command to see what it wants to install.

Comment: @Zacharee1 the whole command? But why does it have to install anything? I'm trying to remove it...

Comment: @DavidFoerster But why does it have to install anything? I'm trying to remove it...

Comment: @DavidFoerster Question updated!

Comment: Run `apt-get upgrade`. I'm pretty sure you have available updates.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've update the question with more details following your advice.

Comment: You ran `apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get` wants to upgrade some packages at the same time as you want to remove `libreoffice-draw`. Of course this requires downloading new packages:

> **8 upgraded**, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 27.9 MB/64.3 MB of archives.

At the same time, the operation frees some space overall:

> After this operation, **15.6 MB disk space will be freed**.

If you run `apt-get upgrade` first, subsequently running `apt-get remove libreoffice-draw`, will no longer require downloading anything. Alternatively you can use the flag `--no-upgrade` to suppress the package upgrades in conjunction with the removal.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `--no-upgrade`!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think it is.
You're uninstalling LibreOffice and an upgrade to completely unrelated packages is trying to occur. Your command output says that 8 apps are to be upgraded, so I'm pretty sure that's where the 30MB download is coming from.